# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 or Linux Mint

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

As the title says I've tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC alongside with Windows 8.1. I used LiLi USB Creator to create a bootable USB stick. The stick is recognized and I can choose it as a boot device. Then this little BIOS like menu pops up where I can choose between testing ubuntu, installing ubuntu, OEM installing ubuntu and check disk for errors or I can open grub. Whatever option I choose it all ends up in the same result (except grub, that seems to work). The following three lines appear for 1/10 second and then the screen stays black forever.

```
[   0.015480] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
[   2.700492] ACPI PCC proble failed.
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
```

Here is what I've tried so far to get it running without success:

1. Check if SecureBoot is disabled (it was)
2. Disabled Windows 8.1 fast boot option
3. Changed from ACPI to IDE and back
4. Tried 3 different USB sticks and a SD Card

The strange thing is that Linux Mint works in live mode fine but always fails with an Input/Output Error while installing.

At last here are the PC specs:

ASRock Fatal1ty Z97X Killer

Intel Core i7 4790K

16GB Crucial Ballistix Sport RAM

2x Palit GeForce GTX970 Jetstream

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to boot with `nomordest`, install Ubuntu, then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Did you [verify the integrity](//help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the disk image(s) used as source to create the installation media?

Comment: I think @Pilot6 has a typo in his comment, and it's suppose to be `nomodeset` OP: You can try this method to achieve this: http://askubuntu.com/a/38834/443563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Nvidia GTX 970 is not compatible with nouveau display driver.

As Pilot6 said, you will have to install using `nomodeset` as a startup parameter during the installation.

After you have installed Ubuntu you have to startup using the recovery menu and install the [xorg-edgers](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) driver.

Comment: Ok that did the trick with the black screen but now I'm also getting the Input/Output Error for the ubuntu installer which previously occured on the Mint installer. Any idea what the problem there is?

Comment: @Hibuja I/O error indicates your hardware may have issues - either the hard drive or the installation disk...